# Issue with Tensorflowhub load on Ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow-hub

I am doing some Tenaordlow Hub based stuff on Windows and Ubuntu and ran into an issue on Ubuntu. So, I did
hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4")

Problem is on Ubuntu, on every restart of computer it redownloads the entire thing but on Windows I have no such issue and it loads in few seconds without needing a download. How do I make sure it jut stores the downloaded one on Ubuntu also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/caching#caching_of_compressed_downloads), the library caches downloads at `os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), "tfhub_modules")`, which is evaluated to `/tmp/tfhub_modules` on Linux. If you want to persist cached models over many reboots, add e.g. `export TFHUB_CACHE_DIR=$HOME/.cache/tfhub_modules` to your `.bashrc` file to change the caching directory to a persistent directory.